# How to find the workspace where the file is checked out in P4v

Tags: p4v

I have a file checked out. So, when I tried to check out the file, it says *"the file is checked out by another user and cannot checkout multiple versions of it"*. I tried seeing the *"checked out by"* tab in P4V and it shows my P4V id. 
But the file is not shown in any of pending lists in any of the work spaces I have.

I need to find the workspace where the file is checked out so that I can revert it.

Answer (score 0):

You can hover your mouse over the item showing the blue checkmark in P4V, and it will show you who has it checked out and in what workspace. In this image, the workspace name is in the red box (but I've blurred it because the name is unimportant).

[image]